# How to get result from os.execvp() in python 2.7?

Tags: python

I am using `os.execvp()` function in python. I am not able to get result of this function.

```
try:
    msi_install_cmd = ['msiexec.exe', '/quiet', '/i ', msi_path.encode('mbcs')]
    os.execvp(msi_install_cmd[0], msi_install_cmd)        

 except Exception, error:   
    raise Exception("MSI installed failed")
```

---

Problem is not able to get return-code or exception from `os.execvp()`.

Comment: And how is that supposed to happen? [`execvp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execvp) replaces the current process with the one executed. When everything works out, the function does not return by design. Did you want to use [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) or similar, instead?

Comment: Thanks dhke. What else I can use where we can get return code ?

Comment: See edit. `check_call()` might be useful in your case (`call()` does not raise an exception on failure).

Answer (score 1):

`os.exec*()` and friends don't return by design. `exec()` replaces the current process with the one invoked. You could think of calling `exec()` as "*stop doing my program here and continue with this program*".

If you want the return code from a (child) process, the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module is a better match:

```
try:
    msi_install_cmd = ['msiexec.exe', '/quiet', '/i ', msi_path.encode('mbcs')]
    subprocess.check_call(msi_install_cmd)

except Exception as error:   
    raise Exception("MSI installed failed: {}".format(error.message))
```